# Could anyone help me on this SQL Query?

Tags: sql

I have a table having some records.(refer below Image)

[image]

In This, I want  **variant_id** based on some condition. Here I tried this query which was not worked for me in the above table.

```
  SELECT distinct variant_id FROM variant_parameter
    WHERE (parameter_id = '2' AND parameter_value IN ( 'M' )) 
    AND (parameter_id = '1' AND parameter_value IN ( 'Black' )) 
    AND variant_id IN ('1','2','3','4','5')
```

Expected Output: **4** but no record coming.

Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: I have removed those conflicting dbms tags. Put one of them back, the one for the dbms actually used.

Comment: Most people here want sample table data _and the expected result_ as formatted text, not as images.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: parameter_id can never be both 2 and 1 for the same row...

Comment: Your query has mutually exclusive `AND` conditions that can never be true in any circumstance. Hint: how can `parameter_id` be both `'2'` and `'1'` at the same time?

Comment: (parameter_id = '2' AND parameter_value IN ( 'M' )) 
    AND (parameter_id = '1' AND parameter_value IN ( 'Black' ))  - cannot logically be both you need an OR and some more brackets

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation and flter with a `having` clause:

```
select variant_id
from variant_parameter
where variant_id between 1 and 5 and parameter_id in (1, 2)
group by variant_id
having
    max(case when parameter_id = 2 and parameter_value = 'M' then 1 end) = 1
    and max(case when parameter_id = 1 and parameter_value = 'Black' then 1 end) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided an MCRE, so this just a guess...

```
SELECT variant_id 
  FROM variant_parameter 
 WHERE (parameter_id = 2 AND parameter_value IN ( 'M' ) )
    OR (parameter_id = 1 AND parameter_value IN ( 'Black' ))
GROUP BY variant_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
 -- AND optional other condition
```